# Searching NodeList by an Array

Tags: java

I have a document that I'm searching through for specific instances, however those instances are specified by the user and there are more than one.  Other than a for loop inside a for loop searching a Nodelist against an array, is there a way I'm missing that wouldn't bog down the system?  Or an easier way?

So far, my code looks like this in abstract:

```
public void sortDoc(Document doc){
    NodeList list = doc.getFirstChild().getChildNodes();
    ArrayList<String> typeList = otherSorter.getTypes();
    for(int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<typeList.size(); j++){
            if(list.item(i).getNodeName()==typeList.get(j)){
                doTheThing();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`List#contains(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) to check for the Node name in the ArrayList.

```
for(int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++){
    if(typeList.contains(list.item(i).getNodeName())){
         // Do Something.
    }
}
```

Also,

```
if(list.item(i).getNodeName()==typeList.get(j)) {
```

**Never Ever** use the above `==` operator for String value comparison.

Always use the [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method for String value comparisons like this:

```
if(list.item(i).getNodeName().equals(typeList.get(j))) {
```

Comment: Huzzah, very simple and neat, thank you, this is far more readable than what I previously had.

Answer (score 1):

See the `contains` function.

```
    public void sortDoc(Document doc){
        NodeList list = doc.getFirstChild().getChildNodes();
        ArrayList<String> typeList = otherSorter.getTypes();
        for(int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++){
            if(typeList.contains(list.item(i)) {
                 //Do Thing
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes but ArrayList does

Comment: I gave it to RJ, he posted first and had a more robust answer, sorry.